# Does periodic acid cleave acetals?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, organic-oxidation

Recently, I started reading about the cleavage reactions done by $\ce{HIO4}$. I came across a statement which read

> $\ce{HIO4}$ can't cleave acetals but it can cleave hemiacetals.

But when I tried to reason out, I thought acetals should have more tendency to get cleaved in acidic medium, because the reverse reaction of acetal formation will have more favourable entropy change than reverse reaction of hemiacetal formation. But this doesn't explain the above statement.

Which part in my reasoning is wrong?