# Does HIO4 cleave hemiacetals?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

I had written in my notes that it does. But I can't find any credible source for it.
A simple Google search only brings up [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/136005/why-doesnt-hio4-cleave-acetals) old and unanswered question.
The questioner failed to specify the source of their extract though. There're not any answers to refer to either. It would be helpful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Since neither questions provide any reliable sources and ask essentially the same using affirmative/negative wording, I edited the origin a bit and closed this question as a duplicate. Anyway, thank you for using search before posting.

Comment: I never knew $\ce{HIO4}$ could cleave either acetals or hemiacetals. I thought it only worked on vicinal diols or diketones.